# facebookModule.forceDialogAuth = true; throws error when calling facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I want my app to use the native ios facebook app features from my iphone in alloy.

However when I try to log in after setting the following to true:

```
"facebookModule.forceDialogAuth = true;"
```

from

```
"facebookModule.forceDialogAuth = false;"
```

the mobile application complains with:

**"FBSession can only be fired form a single thread."**

I suspect this could be due to threading; when turned off the application runs the log in via safari - web view.

My controller is as follows:

```
// Use the Alloy.Globals.Facebook namespace to make Facebook module API calls

var facebookModule = Alloy.Globals.Facebook;

//set facebook app id 

facebookModule.appid = Ti.App.Properties.getString("ti.facebook.appid");



//set permissions i.e what data I want

facebookModule.permissions = ['user_friends','user_photos'];



// Do not force a facebook html popover but use the native dialog if possible

facebookModule.forceDialogAuth = true;


//event handler to listen to user when they have logged in

facebookModule.addEventListener('login', function(e){



    if(e.success){


        alert('You were Logged in');

    //get access token

     var facebook_token = facebookModule.getAccessToken();

    console.log(facebook_token);


    }

});


//invoke method onto button from module

$.fbButton.style = facebookModule.BUTTON_STYLE_WIDE;

$.index.open();
```

How can I resolve this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is a configuration issue with the XCode emulator.

To fix , open the IOS Emulator, then go to the tool bar and press IOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings - you have to do this every time you switch simulators.